# Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app)

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

For my `Nuxt/Vue.js` app I need to export various `Firestore`-related elements as opposed to just `firebase.firestore()`.

However I'm getting some `Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app)` error for the default export and I don't understand why:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
const config = {
  apiKey: '...',
  authDomain: '...',
  databaseURL: '...',
  projectId: '...',
  storageBucket: '...',
  messagingSenderId: '...'
}
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config)
firebase.firestore().settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: false })
const db = firebase.firestore()
const fb = firebase
export { db, fb }
export default firebaseApp
```

There is no duplicate that I can identify in this export default line, so what's wrong?

Answer (score 5):

The way I handle it is I have a firedb file that I import as needed (throughout the App or just in Vuex). Because the file keeps getting referenced, the config keeps re-loading, which causes the same error.

The way I've dealt with it to add this line after the config definition

```
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}
```

I've got an example in condesandbox at https://codesandbox.io/s/vuex-ws-2-60fzg

With your code it would be a little more difficult, since you're exporting the 
`firebaseApp`const. But this may work for you (not tested)

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
const config = {
  apiKey: '...',
  authDomain: '...',
  databaseURL: '...',
  projectId: '...',
  storageBucket: '...',
  messagingSenderId: '...'
}
const firebaseApp = firebase.apps && firebase.apps.length > 0 ? firebase.apps[0] : firebase.initializeApp(config)

firebase.firestore().settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: false })
const db = firebase.firestore()
const fb = firebase
export { db, fb }
export default firebaseApp
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting `Function Firestore.settings() requires its first argument to be of type object, but it was: a custom Object object` error

Answer (score 2):

You can check firebase.apps to see if its loaded. If your only loading it once, then you can just check the length. If you have multiple then you could check each apps name.

// Config file

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";

    const config = {...};

    export default !firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp(config) : firebase.app();

    // Other file
    import firebase from '../firebase';
    ...
    console.log(firebase.name);
    console.log(firebase.database());
```

**If you use firestore, use :**

```
export default !firebase.apps.length
  ? firebase.initializeApp(config).firestore()
  : firebase.app().firestore();
```

Comment: Thanks, I still have problems with other parts of the file though. For `const fb = firebase` then `export { db, fb }`, `fb` isn't recognized and when I use it I get `fb.auth...` is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to export the `firebaseApp`, this should be good enough

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const config = {
  apiKey: '...',
  authDomain: '...',
  databaseURL: '...',
  projectId: '...',
  storageBucket: '...',
  messagingSenderId: '...'
}
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config)
}
firebase.firestore.settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: false })
const db = firebase.firestore()
export { db }
export default firebase
```

This should avoid calling the instantiation more than once

Comment: weird, I only have found this issue when working on the node sdk, you can check if there are any apps already, I just update my answer, take a look at firebase.apps.length

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting this error now: `Function Firestore.settings() requires its first argument to be of type object, but it was: a custom Object object`

Answer (score 0):

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

const config = {
  apiKey: '...',
  authDomain: '...',
  databaseURL: '...',
  projectId: '...',
  storageBucket: '...',
  messagingSenderId: '...'
}
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config)
}
//by commenting this i got my result
// firebase.firestore.settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: false })
const db = firebase.firestore()
export { db }
export default firebase
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

const app = !firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp(info) : firebase.app();

export const auth = app.auth()
export default app;

Answer (score 0):

this my solution in my case reactjs

```js
  if(!firebase.apps.length){
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }else{
    firebase.app();
  }
```